# What financial instrument can I use to profit from unexpectedly small or unexpectedly large dividends?

Tags: stocks, dividends

Suppose company A has paid a very steady dividend of $5 per year for the last 10 years. Suppose I have reason to expect that the next dividend will be substantially greater (e.g. $10) or substantially lower (e.g. $0) than in previous years. What financial instrument allows me to profit from unexpectedly small or unexpectedly large dividends? In other words, how can I profit from unexpected changes in dividends?

Comment: Shareholders experience no immediate benefit from dividends.  Options expiring after the ex-div date would benefit from a totally unexpected large change in the dividend  since the ex-div date would affect the price of the underlying.

Comment: @BobBaerker That second sentence looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @BobBaerker Could you add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

There are [Dividend Futures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dividend_future) that are more commonly traded on indexes, but do exist for single companies (although currently it seems to be through only one exchange, and for European companies).

Like any other financial instrument, though, your ability to trade is dependent on someone being willing to take the other side of that trade, and at what price? So if you think that the dividend will be higher, you'd have to find someone that thinks that the dividend will be *lower* (or at least *not as high*) in order to profit.

To my knowledge, there are no listed options on dividend futures yet.

So - are there instruments that can profit from unexpected changes in dividends? Yes. Are they available (practically) to retail/individual investors? Probably not.

As Bob said in his comment, though - dividends are a net wash for stockholders - if you own the stock (or even if you're short) then dividends are offset by a change in the stock price. Unexpectedly large (or small) dividends can be a source of risk for derivatives (options) traders, though, which is what spawned the dividend future market.